# spring mvc with iframes compared to portlet?

Tags: ajax, spring, iframe, spring-security

I am searching some other ajax technology related to spring.

The main problem is part of html pages has repeated many times, and forcing big part of page to renders continuously ,example one to many relation ship parts.
That is boring to invoke same objects each time in new controllers.

Also writing custom  nested jsp  tag just give me some html pages view code reduction but take to long time developing,also in controller layer I have to invoke object again and reuse them that make heavy unnecessary load ,also force to refactor Involved controllers.
so I need some thing like binding controller to one part of page.
That reusable in any other  jsp page .I know I can do this in ajax but It give me many complex and huge js code. So question is:

Does spring mvc + iframes productive?
Is spring can manage security session with Iframes?
Can It be alternative to portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consideration of choosing ajax vs server-side operation should factor in on user experience, security etc -- not simply based on your development time. Some operation are more appropriate to be done on server side while other on client side / ajax. Keep in mind [combining Spring with Jackson JSON processor](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) helps a lot when developing ajax, POJO can be mapped directly and returned via handler with minimal code.

I wouldn't go with iframe because difficulty of integrating client side items with other components of the page

With regards to having duplicate codes on different controllers, one approach that has worked for me is a common superclass controller approach:

Create a superclass controller that contains shared reusable code (eg: to enrich widget model)

```
public class CommonController {
  @ModelAttribute
  public void enrichWidgetA(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("widgetAMsg", "hello world");
  }
}
```

Extend CommonController on other controller classes

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends CommonController {
  @RequestMapping("/home")
  public String home() {
    // do your stuff here
    return "home";
  }
}
```

On your JSP view you can [utilize JSP tag to keep it DRY](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/07/16/creating-reusable-html-using-jsp-tag/) (Donot Repeat Yourself). `enrichWidgetA` will be invoked prior to `home()` handler method and you can perform business operation for the reusable view component.

Ofcourse the downside of this approach is if you have multiple widget but only some (not all) appear on the page, every single method on `CommonController` decorated with `@ModelAttribute` still runs anyway.

If this is not desirable maybe you can improve this pattern by setting some flags in constructor so the superclass knows which widget enrichment method should (not) be run.